# Calling C++ library function using JNI and which process executes that C++ library

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am new to Java & JNI. This question maybe very newbe. I have C++ library and Java application which interns call the C++ function using JNI concepts.

As per my understanding, JVM loads the C++ dll/SO in JVM space before calling a native function call.

If my understanding on the JVM is correct on JNI. Can someone tell me which/who is going to execute the C++ library function which is loaded inside the JVM.
Let say for C++, there is standard dynamic linker-loader present to handling the dynamic execution part of the C++ and executes all the machine instructions.

In case of JVM loaded JNI Libs (in this case C++ libs), does JVM executes the those libs ? If so does it uses its memory to execute the native function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Java language allows you to mark certain methods as `native`. The Java Native Interface allows you to link these Java methods to a function address in native code.
When you `System.loadLibrary` a library that contains native code, the JVM will do two things:

- Look for [specifically named functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp679) such as `Java_pkg_Cls_f_ILjava_lang_String_2` and link this to the function `f` in class `pkg.Cls`.
- Call `JNI_OnLoad`, if it exists in the library. This can perform initialization and optionally link more native methods using [`registerNatives`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#registering_native_methods).

After this point, the native library indeed resides in the process' memory space like any other library (say, `libcurl` or `libssl`). When you actually **call** one of the `native` methods, the JVM will find the function address and use a native `call` instruction to jump into the function. The function will execute as part of the stack trace of that thread and will show up as such in both the JVM and native stack traces.

In more advanced cases, the library might spawn additional native threads. These work like regular threads in native code and are invisible to the JVM. If these threads need to talk to the JVM as well, the developer can [attach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#attach_current_thread) them.

Comment: Thanks for the Ans. If i understand it correctly, JVM executes the C++ library function (Native function calls). If that is the case, JVM expects bytecode as an IL (Intermediate Language) inorder to execute, but C++ libs say .dll or .so is in machine dependent instructions. How this is handled in the JVM?

Comment: The `native` methods are marked specially in the JVM method table. When you call them, the JVM performs a native call into the linked native function instead of executing bytecode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. So, native funcs are executed as native machine instructions right. If so how dynamic linking or loading performed in JVM. In C++, there is an linker-loader is present if there is an dynamic manipulation are present in the code. How this is handled by JVM process.

Comment: The JVM simply uses the native dynamic loading mechanism. Either `dlopen` on [Linux](https://www.codesearch.cloud/openjdk/xref/jdk9u/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp?r=12470%3Af39d1612915a#1638)/[macOS](https://www.codesearch.cloud/openjdk/xref/jdk9u/hotspot/src/os/bsd/vm/os_bsd.cpp?r=11979%3Ae7203436d63d#1359), or `LoadLibrary` on [Windows](https://www.codesearch.cloud/openjdk/xref/jdk9u/hotspot/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp?r=12530%3A8ae77838f86c#1439).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So in a short description, JVM triggers the C++ library and executes function in JVM env as a native program execution (say for C++, how the main triggered and executes its task, the same way JVM triggers corresponding JNI function and it provides platform to execute as a normal C++ execution procedure).

Comment: While I approve of you trying to rephrase the concept in your own words, please do not make up terms. The JVM *loads* the native library, *links* native function addresses to entries in its method table, and *calls into* these native function addresses. From the standpoint of the native function it was just called by another native function.

Comment: Sure, i am trying to understand from my C++ point of view. What i am not clear is that C++ function in dll/so is executed as same as normal C++ function by the JVM. That all.   
Thanks for being answered to my very basic questions.